# MVC3 - Modifying object before serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently developing a small REST API for my application. It works fine. There's one problem, though. The results returned to the user contain too much data. My controller looks like this:

```
public JsonResult Profile(string name)
{
    var encodedName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(name);
    var n = encodedName.Replace('+', ' ');
    var profile = profileSource.GetProfileForName(n);

    if (profile == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    }

    // XXXXX: how to remove certain fields from the profile?

    return Json(profile, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Any idea what's the cleanest way to deal with this? Is there some way to annotate the profile model so that certain fields won't get serialized? I guess alternatively I could construct a custom Model for this specific case or hack that JsonResult somehow. Either of these ways adds some extra overhead, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LINQ select method to project into an anonymous type.

Comment: +1 I like this approach we you are making a read-only API. But if we are doing a complete REST API with POST a PUT it´s probably more efficient to make a DTO object to share between the actions like I suggest in my answer.

Comment: The API is read-only. Going to investigate this approach further. Sounds promising!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do a custom object with a subset of Profile´s properties. Then translate the original object to the new DTO like object. (Tip:Try AutoMapper). Serialize and return.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Json(new{profile.FirstName, profile.LastName, profile.OtherFields}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using inheritance. Basically I have a "shared" model (base class) and one that derives that and adds some extra fields to it. At the source I simply construct a shared instance for my REST API while the other part of the app uses the derived one. Pretty simple and seems to work well.